# How to spearate Duplicates from csv into separate list in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with 300 000+ rows, i checked the number of duplicates in a column by `.duplicated().sum()` there are 35 968. is there any way i could  get these `35968` in a list of separate `csv` file?

Comment: Please re-structure your post to make the current situation more clear.

- What is lakh?
- Please add a sample to let people understand the problem in a visual way.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do `df[df.duplicated()].to_csv('output.csv')`. This requires that the row is duplicate across all columns.

If you want to drop duplicates if it is duplicate in just one column, use 
`df[df['column'].duplicated()].to_csv('op.csv')`